# Kafka Connect: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, rebalancing

I'm running Kafka Connect on Kubernetes (8-16 nodes, autoscaled). I've defined a total of 44 connectors, one per Kafka topic (one partition per topic). Those topic are produced by Debezium / Postgresql. There are 3 Kafka nodes. Each connector has tasks.max set to 4. Most of my connector (but not every!) has one (always one) failed task, due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition -0.

Not a Kafka expert here, note it ;) I'm presuming that there are 3 Kafka nodes, so 3 workers are doing great, and 4th tasks has nothing to connect to so it fails. But why sometimes there are 4 tasks running just fine?

Also, I have quite often "Conflicting operation due to rebalancing" issue, which can occur for minutes, even hours. Recently I've deleted all pods and they restarted themselves, the problem disappeared, but that's not long term solution.

What's the tasks.max recommended value? Thanks in advance!

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition table-0
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.seek(SubscriptionState.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1501)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.rewind(WorkerSinkTask.java:601)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1200(WorkerSinkTask.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:675)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:406)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1179)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:445)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
```

Sink Connector config:

```
connector.class com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector
autoUpdateSchemas   true
sanitizeTopics  true
autoCreateTables    true
topics  <topic-name>
tasks.max   3
schemaRegistryLocation  http://<ip>:8081
project <big-query-project>
maxWriteSize    10000
datasets    .*=<big-query-dataset>
task.class  com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask
keyfile /credentials/<credentials-file>.json
name    <connector-name>
schemaRetriever com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever
tableWriteWait  1000
bufferSize  100000
```

And it throws above exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for [...]`

Comment: Could you attached some logs?

Comment: @wardziniak I've added trace above, does that help?

Comment: Are you using `io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector` ?

Comment: Yes @wardziniak, but that's not under my control. It's 0.9.2.Final

Comment: What `SinkConnector` throws above exception? Could you attached its configuration.

Comment: @wardziniak added sink config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of property `tasks.max` depends on several factors. Most important one is particular connector. 
Particular Connector depends on its logic and value of `tasks.max` calculate number of `Task`, that will be created. 
ex. `FileStreamSourceConnector` always create 1 Task, so even if you pass value higher then 1 it will create only one.
Same situation is with `PostgresConnector` it *parallel* to one.

`tasks.max` value should also depends on other factors, like: Kafka Connect mode, How many instance of Kafka Connect you have, CPU of machines etc.

How I understand you are using SourceConnector (`PostgresConnector`).
Source Connectors don't poll data from the Kafka. Exception, that you have posted relates to some `SinkConnector`.
If use are using `SinkConnector` your `tasks.max` shouldn't exceed number of partitions. 
If you start more Tasks than the number of partitions some will be idle (status is running, but they don't process data) and rebalancing can occur.

Comment: Not, really. I don't use source connectors at all.

SINK CONNECTORS
38

SOURCE CONNECTORS
0

TOPICS USED BY CONNECTORS
36

Comment: Given your answer above, I'm starting to think that task.max should be 1 in my case, but would like to understad why most of the connectors works fine with `tasks.max - 1` config.

Comment: one partition per topic

Comment: Under the hood Kafka Connect uses _pure_ Consumer, so there is no point to use more than one task in such scenario

Comment: Does it use it for this given BigQuery connector or for sinks in general? That sounds logical but doesn't explain why for some connectors works fine even with 4 tasks...

Comment: It is for all sink connector generally.
Exact number of Task (that is created) is the  size of the list returned by `Connector::taskConfigs`. 
What other connector works without _long_ rebalancing and exceptions?

Comment: I only use big query sinks and they works. I had issue with long rebalancing, but I guess it was related to non unique worker names, which ha been taken from host name as I run it in K8S. Once I change host names to ip, rebalancing issue is gone. But you might be right, I've changed it to to task.max = 1 and will see how it will work.